# Preg split by character and each newline

Tags: php, regex

I am using preg_split, with "u" modifier to split to the characters in php. I have the problem that the newline carriages are not splitted in a single entry, so useing this line:

```
preg_split('//u',"a töxt\n{{image}}", -1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

I get the following result for example:

```
   Array (
    [0] => a
    [1] =>  
    [2] => t
    [3] => ö
    [4] => x
    [5] => t
    [6] =>  { //this line is orginally wrapped and not a space
    [7] => {
    [8] => i
    [9] => m
    [10] => a
    [11] => g
    [12] => e
    [13] => }
    [14] => } )
```

If i am encoding the string before for checking the valid chars i get:

```
Array
(
    [data] => töxt
{{image}}
    [chars] => {t}{�}{�}{x}{t}{
}{{}{{}{i}{m}{a}{g}{e}{}}{}}
    [hex] => {74}{C3}{B6}{78}{74}{0A}{7B}{7B}{69}{6D}{61}{67}{65}{7D}{7D}
    [mb_chars] => {t}{ö}{x}{t}{
}{{}{{}{i}{m}{a}{g}{e}{}}{}}
    [mb_hex] => {74}{F6}{78}{74}{0A}{7B}{7B}{69}{6D}{61}{67}{65}{7D}{7D}
)
```

So any idea how to achieve the result.. It is not only the carriage return but it is the most important actually..

It is a requirement to handle also multibyte characters

Comment: `var_dump(preg_split('//u', "A\nBC", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));`

Comment: I already tried yesterday with PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY and does not split the newline in additional entry in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found a solution for myself to solve my problem:

```
$arr_content = preg_split("/(.|\\\\n)/u",$html_cont, -1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Thanks to anybody who helped finding the trouble ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`str_split function`**](https://www.php.net/str_split) to split a string into character array:

```
$str = "A\nBC";
$chrArray = str_split($str);
print_r($chrArray);
```

**Option 2:**

```
preg_match_all('/./u', "a töxt\n{{image}}", $m);
```

###OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 

    [2] => B
    [3] => C
)
```

**UPDATE:** After trying this out in PHP 5.2.5 I got this

`Warning: preg_split(): Compilation failed: this version of PCRE is not compiled with PCRE_UTF8 support at offset 0 on line 4`

I believe you will need to use an alternate way to break your unicode string into character arrays.

Comment: Definitely consider str_split() instead of preg_split() with an empty expression as a general rule.

Comment: `str_split` is not multi-byte safe (and since he’s using the `u` modifier, I think that might be a requirement).

Comment: @CBroe: Fair point but OP's input string is not showing any non-English letters. OP please specify if this is indeed the requirement.

Comment: @CBroe: As you have rightly commented that using additional `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` will serve well in that case.

Comment: well sorry I forget to mention that the multibytes are still the reason that I used preg_split.

Comment: OK no problems, can you provide s sample of multibyte input that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks but `"a text\n{{image}}"` is also not a `multibyte string`

Comment: See this demo: http://ideone.com/mCHmnx I am also getting same output from both `str_split` and `preg_split` calls. Are you not getting this output?

Comment: no i am getting not this result.. that is this what i want (I just corrected the multibyte example but it is not really important for the line break)

Comment: Hmm weird, what is your PHP version?

Comment: Also see this **update demo with your current example: http://ideone.com/mCHmnx**

Comment: PHP Version is PHP Version 5.2.6-1

Comment: It should work with `PHP 5.2` You can check the demo that it is working. Make sure you use a code editor that supports utf-8 as well.

Comment: how do you know that is working with this php version (nice to know for future). I tried with my code and it is not working. I just uploaded the hex chars of the string.. however the encoding is not even the problem because the line break is the problem..

Comment: I think you right that problem is with PHP 5.2. I tried with `PHP version: 5.2.5` and got `Warning: preg_split(): Compilation failed: this version of PCRE is not compiled with PCRE_UTF8 support at offset 0 on line 4`

Comment: well thank you it seems that i have to iterate manually through the code or do you see any other chance? Can you adjust your answer that i can honour your effort..

Comment: Sure let me add the `PHP 5.2` note to my answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer and continued to find a work aroubd for PHP 5.2 but so far all my attempts get into this same utf-8 warning.